# Rails first or initialize not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have a product.
I have an order.
I have a booking in between.

Whenever I make a booking from the product to the order it saves a new **unique** booking.

It should:

1. Save a new booking when it's the first made from this product.
2. Not make a new booking, but find and overwrite an old one, if the product has already been booked once.
3. If the product has already been booked on the order, but no changes are made, no database transactions are made.

```ruby
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).first_or_initialize
    product = @booking.product
    if @booking.new_record?
      @booking.product_name = product.name
      @booking.product_price = product.price
    else
    @booking.product_quantity = params[:product_quantity]
    @booking.save
    @order.sum_all_bookings 
    @order.save
  end
```

Doesn't work.

**Following worked:**

```ruby
  def create
    @booking = @order.bookings.find_by(product_id: params[:booking][:product_id])
    if @booking
      @booking.product_quantity = params[:booking][:product_quantity]
      @booking.save
    else
      @booking = @order.bookings.new(booking_params)
      @product = @booking.product
      @booking.product_name = @product.name
      @booking.product_price = @product.price
    end
    @order.save
  end
```

Apparently I needed to grab the params, by adding `[:booking]` like in `params[:booking][:product_id]`. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  @order.bookings.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: params[:product_id]).tap do |b|
        # your business logic here
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates you should  setup relations properly and using a database index to ensure uniqueness.

```
class Order
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :products, though: :bookings
end

class Booking
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  validates_uniqueness_of :order_id, scope: :product_id
end

class Product
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :orders, though: :bookings
end
```

The validation here will prevent inserting duplicates on the application level. However it is still prone to race conditions.

```
class AddUniquenessContstraintToBooking < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_index :bookings, [:order_id, :product_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

However the rest of you controller logic is muddled and overcomplicated. I would distinct routes for `update` and `create`:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_order, only: [:create, :index]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:create, :index]

  # POST /orders/:order_id/bookings
  def create
    @booking = @order.bookings.new(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @order
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH /bookings/:id
  def update
    if @booking.update(:booking_params)
      redirect_to @order
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking)
          .permit(:product_id)
  end
end
```

Another alternative is to use `accepts_nested_attributes` - but try to keep it simple.

Comment: This line always fails `@booking = @order.bookings.find_by(product_id: params[:product_id])`, when I do `if @booking`. That's why I currently get entirely new bookings all the time.

Comment: I also found out that the params[..] is not working. I have to make a separate private function for that. My update function is separate because updating is tinkering in the order itself.

Comment: I solved it: Apparently I needed to grab the params, by adding [:booking] like in params[:booking][:product_id]. Happen to know why?